# Re-exporting specific route/slug (statically generate)

Tags: sapper

Is there an option somewhere to regenerate only specific slugs of routes? I imagine it would go as something like starting up CI and comparing generated dates and updated dates, to determine which pages to regenerate.

Comment: Please, can you provide the use case, if possible? Would it save you considerate amount of time?

Comment: It would save time in sense that I'd be able to regenerate more frequently. If someone comments on blog post you regenerate it alone.